# Why the test folder automatically gets created on flutter projects, inside this folder the file widget_test..dart always showing red line(ilke error)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

**It comes all of my Flutter Projects. Is the folder necessary or no**t ?
Do I delete the folder ?

[image]

Comment: According your use, this only use in test case run , is not folder necessary

Comment: Do I delete this folder ?

Comment: Write HomePage() instead ofMyApp()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error and when i move my mouse on it,it shows that **MyApp()** links to another project,e.g:

[image]

and it links to library'package:try_base_flutter/main.dart',then I found every dart file in the lib links to the try_base_flutter.So I search the key word "try_base_flutter",finally I found the wrong code in the **pubspec.yaml**'s first line
,I write the name: try_base_flutter,because I copy the file from the project try_base_flutter,so just change the name,my problem will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Basically `runApp()` method(inside main.dart) contains a class and it should be same as defined in this `tester.pumpWidget(....)` method. If they don't match, it causes this error.

e.g
In your **main.dart** if runApp() method is having a class HomePage
`runApp(const HomePage());` then inside **widget_test.dart** file it should be like  `await tester.pumpWidget(const HomePage());`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `const`. like `await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());`

Comment: Still showing error

Comment: You can delete that directory/folder. It's not needed.

Comment: Surat, Gujarat. Here is my repo if you want to learn Flutter, it will help you more. 
Api calling -> https://github.com/dhola-hardik/flutter_api_call_dio 
State management -> https://github.com/dhola-hardik/flutter_getx_example

Comment: Yah tq very much bro , Will be really helpful